abp blazor disposed object of type SocketsHttpHandler is disposed
When I open my abp v7.1 blazor app in the browser and login. I can use the app perfectly for a couple of minutes after that I always get an error stating the app is trying to access a disposed object. I can only fix this by restarting my iis blazor app.
The error is as folows:
Error: Volo.Abp.Http.Client.AbpRemoteCallException: An error occurred during the ABP remote HTTP request. (Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler'.) See the inner exception for details.

 ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler'.

   at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync[T](ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync[T](String methodName, ClientProxyRequestTypeValue arguments)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.ClientProxies.AbpApplicationConfigurationClientProxy.GetAsync(ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions options)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetRemoteConfigurationAsync()

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.<GetAsync>b__19_0()

   at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func`1 factory, Func`1 optionsFactory, Nullable`1 hideErrors, Boolean considerUow, CancellationToken token)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetAsync()

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemotePermissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync(String name)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemotePermissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, String name)

   at Volo.Abp.Authorization.PermissionRequirementHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler`1.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, Object resource, IEnumerable`1 requirements)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.IsAuthorizedAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync() Blazor.BasicTheme.Global.0FC7E56DDD5146F5685D7C13F585CBC7.js:1:119202
[2024-09-05T13:53:10.139Z] Error: Volo.Abp.Http.Client.AbpRemoteCallException: An error occurred during the ABP remote HTTP request. (Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler'.) See the inner exception for details.

 ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.

Object name: 'System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler'.

   at System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>g__Core|5_0(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync(ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync[T](ClientProxyRequestContext requestContext)

   at Volo.Abp.Http.Client.ClientProxying.ClientProxyBase`1.RequestAsync[T](String methodName, ClientProxyRequestTypeValue arguments)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationConfigurations.ClientProxies.AbpApplicationConfigurationClientProxy.GetAsync(ApplicationConfigurationRequestOptions options)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetRemoteConfigurationAsync()

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.<GetAsync>b__19_0()

   at Volo.Abp.Caching.DistributedCache`2.GetOrAddAsync(TCacheKey key, Func`1 factory, Func`1 optionsFactory, Nullable`1 hideErrors, Boolean considerUow, CancellationToken token)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.MvcCachedApplicationConfigurationClient.GetAsync()

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemotePermissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync(String name)

   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Client.RemotePermissionChecker.IsGrantedAsync(ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal, String name)

   at Volo.Abp.Authorization.PermissionRequirementHandler.HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationHandler`1.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, Object resource, IEnumerable`1 requirements)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.IsAuthorizedAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)

If somebody knows how to fix this without having to restart the app manually that would be really great, because I am out of ideas.
I already tried searhing the web but I couldn't find anything helpfull or something that would fix the issue.
